# How to set linker option in Monodevelop c++ console application

Tags: c++, monodevelop

I'm new to stackoverflow and monodevelop too.
I,m using monodevelop version `2.8.6.3`
//
How can I set linker option in monodevelop.
Since I do followings:

```
Project Option->Code Generation->Libraries
```

and add library `libssl.a`

Project Option->Code Generation->Path
add library path /usr/local/ssl/lib
and include path /usr/local/ssl/include
when I compile/build application I got following error

> -L"/usr/local/ssl/lib" -L"/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib" -l"ssl.a" 
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl.a
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help me!
Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

If you have `libssl.so` you specify with `ssl`

if you have `libssl.a`, just put `libssl.a` in link command

Comment: Almost right, it should be only `ssl`, nothing more. The linker automatically adds the `lib` prefix and the `.a` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

you can easyly change compiler-settings in "Monodevelop":

> > Project->Options->Configurations

in the tab called "code generation" you should be able to add extra Linker-options (like -lm , to instruct the linker to use the c and c++ math-library)
In the section labeled "Extra Compiler - Options" you can provide additional options and the programm-name you wish to provide. (like -o my_programm)

have a closer look to the documentation where it says >> "Changing Compiler Options"

http://monodevelop.com/documentation/creating_c_and_cpp_projects